# I am getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyforms.gui' despite having pyforms-gui installed

Tags: python, pip, pyforms

I am trying to run a program. It said in it's readme to install requirements first, so I did and it installed pyforms and python_docx
But now when I execute command 
    python  
and i get the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyforms.gui'

How can that be fixed?

I tried manually installing pyforms-gui and got message that I already have this module installed.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pyforms
from pyforms.controls import ControlButton
from pyforms.gui.controls.ControlEmptyWidget import ControlEmptyWidget #problematic line
from pyforms.gui.controls.ControlProgress import ControlProgress
from generation import Project
from widgets.stage_13 import Stage13Window
from widgets.stage_5 import Stage5Window
from .initial_data_editor import InitialDataEditor
```

Answer (score 0):

Your import statement is incorrect. The correct imports are given [here](https://pyforms.readthedocs.io/projects/Pyforms-GUI/en/v4/api-reference/controls.html#controlemptywidget). Note that `pyform.gui` is now `pyforms_gui`.

```py
from pyforms_gui.controls.control_emptywidget import ControlEmptyWidget
from pyforms_gui.controls.control_progress import ControlProgress
```